# Call nested method in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my vuejs app, I have 2 methods. If I write method1 like this, It won't run.

```
method1: function(param1, param2){
    // I can log param1 in here
    thirdLib.debounce(function(param1, params2){
        // It doesn't run into here
        // Do something
    }, 100)
},
method2: function(){
    this.method1(param1, param2);
}
```

However, if I change method1 to this, it works smoothly:

```
method1: thirdLib.debounce(function(param1, params2){
            // Do something
        }, 100)
```

I wonder why it happends? In case I want to write method1 like the first one, how can I do it?
My vue version is 3.8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without exactly seeing what thirdlib is, this happens because thirdLib.debounce() creates a debounce method, it doesn’t execute it.  So in your first example, where are you executing it?  You’re not you just declare it and throw it away.  But because you want the same debounce instance to be called every time (that’s how it knows to debounce), I don’t even think the first example would work as a debounce if you did get it to execute because every call would create a new debounce instance.

So this is really more of a Javascript thing and less of a vue thing.

Comment: So your point is the `thirdLib.debounce()` just declare, it doesn't automatic execute right?
For example, if I change `debounce` to `setTimeout`, it run automatically after timeout, however this `debounce` function just declare so I need call in somewhere else.

Comment: Well setTimeout is different from debounce.  

The purpose of setTimout is to execute a method after the time provided time expires.  So it starts counting down right away and returns an id you can use to cancel it.  Calling setTimout multiple times will start multiple timers and multiple executions of the passed in method.

Comment: The purpose of debounce is to prevent multiple executions of a method if it gets called repeatedly in a given timeframe.  So each time a debounce function is called the timer restarts until finally it stops getting called and the provided method executes.  Internally debounce creates all the plumbing for that, often with setTimeout.  So you have to create it, and creating it doesn’t execute it, and you don’t want creating it to execute it, you want to treat it just like any other method (only now it’s denounced)

Comment: You are my hero. You save my day.

Answer (score 0):

it is because you need a callback as params for `thirdLib.debound`. The code you showed here actually define a callback with two parameters, you called it the same name param1, param2.

You just need to write another method as

`method3: thirdLib.debound(param1, param2)....`
Then you pass it as

`method1: function(param1, param2){
    // I can log param1 in here
    this.method3(param1, param2);
}`